# ASP.NET Repeater never hits ItemBound function

Tags: asp.net

I have the following Repeater:

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpttsk" runat="server"> 
                <HeaderTemplate> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
                            <b>ID</b> 
                        </td> 
                        <td> 
                            <b>Date</b> 
                        </td> 

                    </tr> 
                </HeaderTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
                            <%#Eval("ID")%> 
                        </td> 

                        <td> 
                            <%#Eval("PerfDate", "{0:MMM d, yyyy}")%> 
                        </td> 

                    </tr> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I am putting the code in the code behind file

```
    Protected Sub rpttsk_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpttsk.ItemDataBound
```

but when I put a break point it never hits it. Any idea?

Comment: you have to add handler to OnItemDataBound property of the repeater: OnItemDataBound="rpttsk_ItemDataBound"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to your ASPX page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpttsk" OnItemDataBound="rpttsk_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

Comment: He is using vb.net. So as long as he has "Handles" in codebehind he doesnt need to specify in aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a datasource you are binding to the repeater, if you do not the OnItemDataBound event will not fire.